# Using a MongoDB Trigger to Update Collection with async HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, triggers, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I have a project where I need to get a bunch of item data via an API for an online game's marketplace.  The way their system works plus the amount of calls I'd need to make means that doing it all from within my application isn't possible.

I was using Google Sheets with a script + timer, but it's long past time I migrated to an actual database system for better support, ability to optimize, and of course, to learn and grow.

So, I'm using and learning MongoDB and am working to write a Trigger function(s) to auto-update these documents every x amount of time.  This means using passing the itemId for each doc (item) into an async function that fires an HTTP Request out to an endpoint and using that value to set a field.

What I have tried currently looks like:

```
exports = async function()
{
   var coll = context.services.get("myCluster").db("myDB").collection("myColl");

   items.updateMany(
     {},
     [{ $set: { lastUpdate: new Date(), itemPrice: await getPrice("$itemId") } }])
   .then(result =>
   {
      // some logging
   })
   .catch block to log errors
};

async function getPrice(itemId)
{
   // do an await context.http.get() with the url + itemId
   // parse out the JSON and return the data I want
}
```

I know I can use a field to set another field and have had no trouble with that.  I could replace the `await getPrice` with `"$itemId"` and it would copy the value from the one field to the other.

If I place the field string into a function, however, it seems to resolve the function and just send the string literal instead of evaluating the field for the result first.  So, I'm guessing this is some issue with how/when prvalues (or Mongo/Atlas/JS's version of them) are evaluated?

It feels like using the Aggregation Pipeline is the right move here considering what the documentation says about it, but I can't find anything talking about calling functions using field values as parameters.

update 7/8/2023

I coded a workaround, however, I'm sure it's much less efficient than my first thought and attempt using `updateMany()`.

I separated the process into 3 steps:

1. Use a coll.find() and use the returned cursor to fill an idArray
2. Use that idArray to fill a priceArray
3. Use both to update the collection's documents

I'll add a good chunk docs later as a test and see how it runs as I had only inserted a few for testing the trigger.